# Tabula / PDF column units

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, tabula

I am automating the extraction of tabular data from a PDF file. I need to use an open source library called [Tabula](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-java). The tool has an option to feed it columns to separate tabular PDF data like so:

```
-c 80, 250, 380
```

The above would create 5 columns; the 80, 250 and 380 are units for column separators.

Can anyone tell me what the 80, 250 and 380 are units of and how to determine what horizontal spot on the page is what number? Are there common units that PDFs are measured in that these may be?

Comment: What happened when you used that code and measured?

Comment: It looks like 300 puts me in the middle of the pdf page..

Comment: Best I found is a ratio I created between the actual acrobat ruler and these numbers, but I just think these have to stand for something

Comment: The native measurement unit of the PDF file format is the Typographic Point (As Adjusted By Adobe): 1/72 of an inch. That puts your "300" smack in the middle of an A4 document, at 10.5 cm, or quite nearby for a Letter or Legal sheet, at 4 1/6th inch.

Comment: Gotcha, I think that works. If you post it as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1):

In the docs there's a section that explains [how to grab the coordinates from the tabula app](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-java/wiki/Using-the-command-line-tabula-extractor-tool#grab-coordinates-of-the-table-you-want).

The coordinates also appear in the "Console" tab of the Developers Tools in the browser after selecting the area or areas you want and clicking "Preview & Export Extracted Data".